# How to implement Ant Lion Optimization (ALO) feature selection for KNN Classification Problems?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, text-classification, k-nn, tfidf

I have been assigned for a project related to text data classification, i have preprocess and vectorized the data with TF-IDF. For feature selection i am using pyMetahueristic library to implement ALO feature for KNN with code as below

```
def _target_func(self, x):

    selected = x > 0.5
    num_selected = selected.sum()
    if num_selected == 0:
        return 1.0

    # model = KNeighborsClassifier()
    # model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
    # y_pred = model.predict(self.X_test)

    accuracy = cross_val_score(KNeighborsClassifier(), self.X_train[:, selected], self.y_train, cv=2, n_jobs=-1).mean()
    score = 1 - accuracy
    num_features = self.X_train.shape[1]
    
    alpha = 0.99

    return alpha * score + (1 - alpha) * (num_selected / num_features)

alo = ant_lion_optimizer(target_function= knn._target_func, **parameters) 
best_features = alo[:-1]
best_fitness = alo[-1]

print(f'Selected Features: {best_features} ')
print(f'Maximum Fitness Score : {best_fitness}')
datasets_feature_selection['ALO'][label] = (knn.X_train[:, best_features], 
                                            knn.X_test[:, best_features], 
                                            knn.y_train, knn.y_test)

knn_feature_selected = KNN(label, datasets_feature_selection['ALO'][label])
knn_feature_selected.train(param_grid=param_grid)
knn_feature_selected.evaluate()
```

But after selection process model resulting in poorer performance from 78% testing accuracy to 74%. Is there possibly something i did wrong or could to make fix it? Thanks you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.